# Matlab: Plotting / Simplifying parametrized functions with fixed Parameters

Tags: matlab, plot, parameters, simplify

I have function in this case a cost function for categorisation in machine learning that hat 3 variables: y, x, theta

`j = y*log(1/(exp(-theta*x) + 1)) - log(1 - 1/(exp(-theta*x) + 1))*(y - 1)`

The questions for matlab:

1. how can I set e.g. y=0 and then plot j as j(y=0, theta, x) as a surface plot with fsurf(j)?

   - I tried equating y=0 and then fsurf(j): error
   - I tried assume (y=0): error
2. Same as with plot just with simplify function.

Of course, no. 2 I can do in my mind or on paper. So that's more kinda how-to question for matlab for later, more complicated uses.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subs` first, and then plot the function by substituting `theta` by `y`,as it is needed the variables be `x` and `y`:

```
fsurf(subs(subs(j, 'y', 0), 'theta', 'y'))
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I looked for.